# Transfer universal collection to function

Tags: scala, input, collections, parameters, transfer

How do I transfer either an array or a list to a function? That is, pass a universal collection. I want, that "foreach" work like with collections.

```
  def sortCollections(collection: Any): Unit = {
    collection.foreach(...)
  }
```

Comment: Depending on your end goal you may either use a interface like `Iterable` or `IterableOnce`, or you may need more machinary like using the `Ops` traits. Or maybe a **cats** typeclass like `Functor`

Comment: Can you give an example of implementation? I don’t quite understand your answer

Comment: I am not answering, I am telling you that is not possible to answer because there are many ways to _"abstract over collections"_ all with trade-offs, and choosing the right approach depends on the specific context. Thus, I would either recommend you to google the alternatives I mentioned so you can _(with time)_ make an informed decision, or add more details to your question so we can provide a specific answer. Unless, all you actually care is just `foreach`?

Comment: No, it’s important to me that any indexed collection can be converted into an array.

Comment: _Foreach_ - is example of how to run through the collection

Comment: Well, in that case you can just ask for `IndexedSeq` which has a `toArray` method _(note, you will also need an `implicit ev: ClassTag[T]`)_ - However, may I ask, what is even the point of such function? Also, why an `Array`?

Comment: My idea is to create a recursive function that sorts any collection, and an array is the most popular output

Comment: Popular for who? `Array` is almost never used for **Scala** developers. Anyways, what is even the point of your function when all collections have `sorted` and friends? There is also: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Sorting$.html - And forgetting about that, nobody would want a function that sorts but changes your collection type to `Array`, or `List` or whatever, you would expect it to return the same type, and that is harder than just asking for `IndexedSeq`, which again is my point that you need to be clear about what you want.

Comment: Anyways check this: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/custom-collection-operations.html